# How can I get My previous route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

How can I get my previous router in my current controller.

```
App.MyController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    next:function() { // This is my action helper in HBS
        this.transitionTo('nextPage');
    },
    back:function() { // This is my action helper in HBS
        // Here I need to dynamically identify my previous route.
        // How can I get my previous route.
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831668/the-route-i-came-from-or-previous-route

Comment: I'm also working this issue.  It would be nice in a later MVC version if there was something like:  Request.RawUrl.PreviousRoute

Comment: Just do `history.back()`. That's how Ember is designed to work. There's no need to build a whole bunch of machinery to maintain your own history. The browser already keeps its own.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After having inspected the router object again, I don't see any property in there that will allow you to grab the last route. In pre 4 there was a property for the last route, but it was a difficult property to work with.

My solution is therefore the same as it was in pre 4: I'd create my own mixin to handle the routes that you navigate into, and from that list of routes, you can get whatever route you're after: the current one, the last one, et cetera...

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sMtNG/

**Mixin**

The first thing to do is create the mixin that will allow us to push the routes into a `HistoryController`. We can do this by creating a `setupController` method which of course gets invoked every time you move into a route.

```
App.HistoryMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    setupController: function() {
        this.controllerFor('history').pushObject(this.get('routeName'));
    }
});
```

We are pushing the route into the `HistoryController`.

**History Controller**

Since we're currently pushing the `routeName` into a non-existent `HistoryController`, we'll need to go ahead and create that, which is absolutely nothing special.

```
App.HistoryController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

**Index Controller**

Since the `HistoryController` stores the list of routes we've navigated into, we'll need it accessible on other controllers, such as the `IndexController`, we'll therefore use `needs` to specify in which controller it should be accessible.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['history']    
});
```

**Implement Mixin**

We now have everything we need to keep a track of the routes, and so we'll specify that our routes need to implement this mixin.

```
App.CatRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.HistoryMixin);
```

**Template**

Last but not least, now that we have a `HistoryController` which our `IndexController` can access, and the mixin pushes each accessed route into the `HistoryController`, we can use our application view to output a list of the routes, and specify the last route. Of course in your case you'll need the last route minus one, but there's no sense in me doing everything!

```
<h1>Routes History ({{controllers.history.length}})</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Last Route: {{controllers.history.lastObject}}</li>
    {{#each controllers.history}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I hope this gets you onto the straight and narrow.

Comment: This works for non dynamic routes. Would this approach work for routes with dynamic segments?

Comment: Don't you need to call `_super` from your `setupController` in the mixin?

Comment: Seems way too complicated

Answer (score 0):

Current solutions feel like the tail wagging the dog.

Simple solution is to do `window.history.back()`

Ember doesn't keep track of the router history, since it would be redundant. All browser already handle this by default.