# User flow assistance

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on an `Ember.js` application that contains several models with dependencies.  For example, when setting up a model for `Client` I include the attribute `portfolios : DS.hasMany('Portfolio')`

When a user enters the app, they are presented an option to immediately add a new portfolio at the route `portfolio.add` where among other form fields they are presented a drop down to select the client for whom they are creating the portfolio, as well as an option to create a new client via `{{#link-to client.add}}`.  This is NOT the only way a user could get to the route client.add

I'd like for Ember to remember that the user got to the client.add route via portfolio.add, change the text of the submit button to indicate that they will return to portfolio.add after saving, and to transition back to portfolio.add after the promise returns successfully where it will auto select the newly created client in the drop down.

So far I've thought I'd use this answer: [How can I get My previous route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000494/how-can-i-get-my-previous-route) to check the previous route, and possibly create a similar mixin for storing a reference to the created client record.

It's a hack, and I'd rather pass related objects/properties directly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up advancing my Ember build to Canary and including `Ember.FEATURES["query-params"] = true;`

I then added a `routedFrom` parameter when shifting into a view that would need to route back on completion and in the original route's model I added `this.transitionTo('originalroute',{routedFrom:null});` to clear the `routedFrom` parameter.

Comment: While using a query param is probably the best solution here, I'm not marking my own answer correct as long as query-params is only available in the canary build via flag.  There is discussion of including it in the next release, and if that happens then I'll revisit here.